# Connection times out with error code 110 even before the time runs out while making a websocket call

Tags: rust, websocket, substrate

I want to make a WebSocket call in Rust but the code is throwing a TransportError:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Transport(Error when opening the TCP socket: Connection timed out (os error 110))', src/main.rs:20:10
```

I checked my Vultr instance, it does not have a firewall enabled.

My code sets a connection timeout:

```
use jsonrpsee_ws_client::WsClientBuilder;
use std::time::Duration;
use subxt::ClientBuilder;

#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "polkadot_metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot {}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    env_logger::init();
    // let connection_timeout_secs = Duration::new(secs: 60, nanos: 0);
    let connection_timeout_duration = Duration::new(600, 0);

    let url = "wss://moonriver.api.onfinality.io:9944/public-ws";

    let client = WsClientBuilder::default()
        .connection_timeout(connection_timeout_duration)
        .build(url)
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let api = ClientBuilder::new()
        .set_client(client)
        // .set_url("wss://pub.elara.patract.io:9944/statemine")
        .build()
        .await?
        .to_runtime_api::<polkadot::RuntimeApi<polkadot::DefaultConfig>>();

    let mut iter = api.storage().system().account_iter(None).await?;

    while let Some((key, account)) = iter.next().await? {
        println!("{}: {}", hex::encode(key), account.data.free);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I set a timer and instead of 10 minutes, the error was thrown in 6-7 minutes. This makes me think that it is not an actual timeout error but something else, like network settings. But I ensured there is no firewall enabled from the [Vultr UI](https://my.vultr.com/).

Comment: Does changing `.unwrap()` to `.ok()` make a difference?

Comment: I am trying that out now, but eventually, I will have to `unwrap()` it as the `set_client(client)` requires `client` to be of `WSClient` type.

Comment: The `.ok()` did not throw any error but I removed the rest of the code: https://pastebin.com/hY4XkmFM.

Now, checking to do `.unwrap()` after `.ok()`.

Comment: If I try to `unwrap()` after `ok()`, I get the error:
```thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/main.rs:24:25
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace```

Answer (score 1):

It should be port `443`.
You can debug stuff like this with [wscat](https://github.com/websockets/wscat), I highly recommend it.

> wscat -c wss://moonriver.api.onfinality.io:443/public-ws

You probably saw this, but for everyone else: a simple example to check the connection can be found in the [subxt examples](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/fetch_remote.rs).